# bash error renaming files with spaces - mv target is not a directory

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, rename, mv

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files which contain spaces in them, getting rid of the spaces.  I thought I found the correct bash command:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv \"$f\" ${f/ /}; done
```

However, this gives the error, "mv: target  is not a directory" for each file.  If I replace 'mv' with 'echo mv' in the command, it prints the proper mv command for each file, and if I type any of those mv commands individually, they work. For example, if I have 2 files, "a .txt", and "b .txt", and run the command above, I get:

```
mv: target 'a.txt' is not a directory
mv: target 'b.txt' is not a directory
```

If I type the command:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo mv \"$f\" ${f/ /}; done
```

I get:

```
mv "a .txt" a.txt
mv "b .txt" b.txt
```

I've found another way to do this, using "rename", but I would like to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm wondering how you put spaces before the .txt because it won't accept that. It will think .txt is not a directory

Answer (score 44):

Try:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "${f// /}"; done
```

Three points:

1. The quotes around a shell variable should not be escaped.
2. In general, it is a good idea to put double-quotes around every reference to a shell variable.
3. `${f/ /}` removes just the first occurrence of a space.  To remove all spaces, use `${f// /}`.

#### What went wrong

```
$ touch {a,b}" .txt"
$ ls *.txt
a .txt  b .txt
$ for f in *.txt; do mv \"$f\" ${f/ /}; done
mv: target `a.txt' is not a directory
mv: target `b.txt' is not a directory
```

The expression `\"$f\"` does not behave like it is double quoted.  It expands to two arguments, such as `"a` and `.txt"`, where the double-quotes are treated as normal characters, just like the `a` is a normal character.  Because there are three arguments to `mv` (`"a` and `.txt"` and `a.txt`), `mv` believes that you are trying to move the first two arguments to the third and the third is required to be a directory.  Since the third is not a directory, it issues an error message.

Comment: Is there a way to keep spaces? And still, rename the file? I'm getting mv: target <Transparent-300-400.png> is not a directory, but the full name of the file is "Jam Banner Transparent.png", I take the name add size and rename it, but still have this error. The files that have "_" instead of spaces are renamed as expected. I expect it to be "Jam Banner Transparent-300-400.png"

Comment: @CandidMoon If you are getting the "not a directory" message, that likely means that the shell variables weren't in double-quotes.  Of course, without knowing what, precisely, you are doing, I can only guess.

Comment: https://ideone.com/yQaViz this is my code, I use imagemagick and cowsay. I know that it would be better if I created a new question about it because of the points, though thanks for replying.

Comment: I see: `convert $fullfilename -resize ${new_width_height[0]}x${new_width_height[1]} $new_file_name`  If the file names contain spaces, they need to be inside double-quotes.

Answer (score 12):

Because this is the first thing that came up on google when googling this error, I thought I'd add a bit.

**This error occurs if you have more than two arguments and the last result is not a directory.**

This works (when output.txt does not exist):

```
mv file1.txt output.txt
```

This does not (if file2.txt does exist):

```
mv file1.txt file2.txt
```

In my case I was doing: `mv prefix_* output_file_name` to ensure a downloaded file had a consistant name, but another file had appeared in the directory, restulting in the "mv target is not a directory" error

Comment: looks like you have 2 arguments after `mv` in both cases .. what am I missing?

Comment: Indeed. I've just clarified that in one case the file did not exist and in the other it did.