# How to rename files using wildcard in bash?

Tags: bash

I was trying to rename some files to another extension:

```
# mv  *.sqlite3_done *.sqlite3
```

but got an error:

```
mv: target '*.sqlite3' is not a directory
```

Why?

Comment: I think this has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519301/bash-error-renaming-files-with-spaces-mv-target-is-not-a-directory Does that sort it for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wildcard expansion results in multiple names being passed to the command.  The shell thinks you are trying to move multiple files to the `*.sqlite3` directory.

You need to use a loop:

```
for nam in *sqlite3_done
do
    newname=${nam%_done}
    mv $nam $newname
done
```

The `%_done` says to remove the last occurrence of `_done` from the string.

If you may have spaces in your filenames you will want to quote the filenames.

Answer (score 10):

`mv` can only move multiple files into a single directory; it can’t move each one to a different name. You can loop in bash instead:

```
for x in *.sqlite3_done; do
    mv -- "$x" "${x%_done}"
done
```

`${x%_done}` removes `_done` from the end of `$x`.

Answer (score 9):

the easy way is use find

```
find . -type f -name '*.sqlite3_done' -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; mv "$x" "${x%_done}"' \;
```

Comment: Bash-easy is not the ordinary easy.