# Removing unknown / non-specific string after file extension on file names

Tags: bash, macos, sed, terminal, rename

Trying to remove a string that is located after the file name extension, on multiple files at once. I do not know where the files will be, just that they will reside in a subfolder of the one I am in.

Need to remove the last string, everything after the file extension. File name is:

**something-unknown.js?ver=12234.... (last bit is unknown too)**

This one (below) I found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703862):

```
for nam in *sqlite3_done
do
    newname=${nam%_done}
    mv $nam $newname
done
```

I know that I have to use % to remove the bit from the end, but how do I use wildcards in the last bit, when I already have it as the "for any file" selector?

Have tried with a modifies bit of the above:

```
for nam in *.js*
do
    newname=${ nam .js% } // removing all after .js
    mv $nam $newname
done
```

I´m in MacOS Yosemite, got bash shell and sed. Know of rename and sed, but I´ve seen only topics with specific strings, no wildcards for this issue except these:

[How to rename files using wildcard in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703801/how-to-rename-files-using-wildcard-in-bash)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227640/rename-first-part-of-multiple-files-with-mv

Comment: **So, to tie this one off:** Here is my final version of this solution, specifically here for JS files with wordpress type file-url-extensions:

`for x in $(find . -type f -name '*.js*');do mv -v $x $(echo $x | sed 's/\.js.*/.js/'); done`

and here it is in foo:

`for x in $(find . -type f -name '*.foo*');do mv -v $x $(echo $x | sed 's/\.foo.*/.foo/'); done`

Note the `-v` I added, for verbose mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for in terms of parameter substitution:

```
$ ls -C1
first-unknown.js?ver=111
second-unknown.js?ver=222
third-unknown.js?ver=333

$ for f in *.js\?ver=*; do echo ${f%\?*}; done
first-unknown.js
second-unknown.js
third-unknown.js
```

Note that we escape the `?` as `\?` to say that we want to match the literal question mark, distinguishing it from the special glob symbol that matches any single character.

Renaming the files would then be something like:

```
$ for f in *.js\?ver=*; do echo "mv $f ${f%\?*}"; done
mv first-unknown.js?ver=111 first-unknown.js
mv second-unknown.js?ver=222 second-unknown.js
mv third-unknown.js?ver=333 third-unknown.js
```

Personally I like to output the commands, save it to a file, verify it's what I want, and then execute the file as a shell script.

If it needs to be fully automated you can remove the echo and do the `mv` directly.

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -i` or `-n` when doing mass renames/moves like this, to avoid data loss in case of name conflicts.

Comment: I just verified that this worked! It takes all files in one single folder and renames all past ".js" into only ".js". So "anything-here.js?ver=12345" into "anything-here.js". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in $(find . -type f -name '*.js*');do mv $x $(echo $x | sed 's/\.js.*/.js/'); done
```

Comment: I just verified that this worked as well. It takes all files in the **current folder AND all sub-folders** and removes all strings in file names past "**.js**". So "**anything-here.js?ver=12345**" becomes "**anything-here.js**". Thanks.

Comment: Using `sed`, this is the most **efficient** one for me, recursively going through all files in current folder and sub folders.